# Does Mongo make a mistake like this?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Say I have a User Document, filled with arrays of ObjectIds.
They are references to documents in another collection.

I want to load all things from a particular user's array. So I do:

```
find({ _id: $in : someArrayOfObjectIds})
```

It's possible that certain references reference something that has been deleted.
So the resulting array of the above "find" call can be smaller then the someArrayOfObjectIds.

So for all the ObjectIds not found can I now safely assume that that document does not exist anymore, or can my query just fail to find a document (does mongo make a mistake).

Comment: FYI: mongodb doesn't make a mistake. It doesn't have referential integrity on documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can safely assume that missing documents do not exist. By the way, your query is invalid. Should be this:

```
find({ _id: {$in : someArrayOfObjectIds}})
```

> or can my query just fail to find a document

If it was possible, no one would use it. Pen and paper approach is a safer alternative that DB that makes such mistakes :)